# Problems with Sliding tab layout and view pager in pre lollipop device

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on app that requires me to implement tabs. i stumbled on material design sliding tabs. It worked all fine on lollipop but on android 4.1 the toolbar and the tabs dissappear as shown below

http://tinypic.com/r/1rztzb/8

but on lollipop it looks like this

http://tinypic.com/r/egzcdg/8

below is my xml view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>


    <com.example.nappy.goodies.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerhome"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#EEEEFF"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home"
        android:color="#EEEEFF"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:rippleColor="#ff00786a"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    layout="@layout/recycler">
</include>
```

please what could i be missing here, i have all the dependecies included in my app build.gradle like below

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved to Android design library's TabLayout. SlidingTabLayout works but it does have issues.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

And also can you set viewpager to come below tabs by adding this attribute to viewpager

```
android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
```

Comment: do you suggest i use tablayout instead? Dont understand

Comment: yup I am suggesting you to keep tabLayout instead of slidingtablayout and also dont you have to keep viewpager as layout_below tabs

Comment: I did add the viewpager below tabs and it worked for me, thank you so much for this help. But i dont understand why it works like that on lollipop

Comment: I was assuming setViewPager on the tablayout/slidingtablayout had taken care of this in lollypop where as not handled in previous versions. Dont have anyway to validate though.